# NodeJS - Download/Use JS file from CDN

Tags: javascript, node.js, cdn

I'm creating an application written in NodeJS that contains many classes. Though I plan to make this just a personal application, I plan to give it to a small group of people. The issue I have is that some of the JS classes I edit a lot, and sending those with the app a new download link every time is a hassle (for both of us).

I've been looking into possible solutions and noticed some applications download a few JS files from a CDN or something of the sort when initiating the program. I was curious how I could proceed with doing this? After extensive googling I wasn't able to find anything related to the subject, so I've came here *(the most I found was downloading the file, putting it in a folder somewhere, and then requiring it in the other JS files, but I'm sure there's a better solution than that as that comes with many flaws).*

A few things to note:

- I don't plan to make my entire app be downloaded, just a few files/classes that I edit a lot.
- I plan to use a CDN or something of the sort to serve the JavaScript files that I wish to download.
- I plan to download them when the app initializes, so no classes contained in the files download would be missing when they are actually used in other parts of the code.

If it helps in any way, I use electron for my application and electron-builder to package it.

Any help or pointing me in the right direction would be great, thanks!

Comment: I don't understand fully what you're trying to do but maybe do a `GET` request to your JS files and write them to a folder somewhere that you then require? If it's for the front-end you just add it to the HTML like normal.

Comment: @CodeDraken - That's what I read online from the small amount of information that there was, but I see a lot of flaws in that. For instance, I don't want the file to still be there after the app closes, there also may be permission issues with reading/write the file, and the path I require may not be correct depending on the users file structure.

Comment: I agree there should be a better way - that's just the first that comes ti mind. You could remove the files once the app closes, I believe there's a `onClose` event in Electron. For the path Electron also provides some tools for standard cross platform paths to put your app data. I believe it's `app.getPath('appdata')`
https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/app.md#appgetpathname

Answer (score 0):

Just download and run it through [`vm`](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#vm_script_runincontext_contextifiedsandbox_options) (via any of the suitable methods), or [`cp.execFile(file)`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfile_file_args_options_callback), or (experimental) workers [`new Worker(file)`](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html#worker_threads_new_worker_filename_options)

However, I wouldn't look for more alternative, since your use case is very uncommon and even dangerous. Distribute via npm modules instead, as you describe exactly the module use case.